# Why cant I access object property in Angular even the property exists. but the same is possible with JS only

Tags: javascript, angular

```
this.getdata().pipe().subscribe(data=>console.log(data))
```

whihc gives me

```
 {total: 4, page: 1, page_size: 100, cursor: null, result: Array(4), …}
cursor
: 
null
page
: 
1
page_size
: 
100
result
: 
Array(4)
0
: 
{token_address: '0x8c5b9dc5fe8a1151116bfcfb4207912ea0090b60', token_id: '4', amount: '1', owner_of: '0x8b61fc3df7a5dd1972f6187fbc3cc374e9845d2b', token_hash: '91c42919fc66f3988c1e9b0f68aef720', …}
1
: 
{token_address: '0x8c5b9dc5fe8a1151116bfcfb4207912ea0090b60', token_id: '3', amount: '1', owner_of: '0x8b61fc3df7a5dd1972f6187fbc3cc374e9845d2b', token_hash: '98a03354565f77ade5bfacb80d1b46ae', …}
2
: 
{token_address: '0x8c5b9dc5fe8a1151116bfcfb4207912ea0090b60', token_id: '2', amount: '1', owner_of: '0x8b61fc3df7a5dd1972f6187fbc3cc374e9845d2b', token_hash: '7c3a9cd240803578eaf35de07effdb33', …}
3
: 
{token_address: '0x8c5b9dc5fe8a1151116bfcfb4207912ea0090b60', token_id: '1', amount: '1', owner_of: '0x8b61fc3df7a5dd1972f6187fbc3cc374e9845d2b', token_hash: '60a8b1abf25235b3b35d871e0feaebdb', …}
length
: 
4
[[Prototype]]
: 
Array(0)
status
: 
"SYNCED"
total
: 
4
```

1)I can access result array with JS just like this

```
const options = {
 method: 'GET',
 url: 'https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/0x8b61FC3df7a5Dd1972f6187Fbc3cc374e9845D2b/nft',
 params: {chain: 'mumbai', format: 'decimal', normalizeMetadata: 'false'},
 headers: {accept: 'application/json', 'X-API-Key': 'api'}
};
axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
console.log(response.data.result);}).catch(function (error) {console.error(error);});
```

2)But why cant I do it in Angular

```
 getdata(){
    return this.http.get('https://deep-index.moralis.io/api/v2/0x8b61FC3df7a5Dd1972f6187Fbc3cc374e9845D2b/nft',
    {headers:new HttpHeaders({accept: 'application/json','X-API-Key':this.api,format: 'decimal', normalizeMetadata: 'false'}),params:new HttpParams().set('chain','mumbai')});
  }
      getId(data:any){
    this.ItemClicked = data;
    this.defaultView = true
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getdata().pipe().subscribe(data=>console.log(data?.result))
  }
```

which gives me the error Property 'result' does not exist on type 'Object'. What am I not understanding here and what should I be doing instead?

I'm using subscribe because I want to do something with the data and since the HTTPS gives me an Observable.

Comment: What is in data? Did you console.log only data, without result?

Comment: yes the one I have provided is only data i.e. - this.getdata().pipe().subscribe(data=>console.log(data))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTTPClient functions to perform HTTP requests are generic. Since you didn't pass the response type to it, your IDE will show this error.

You now have different options, but this is definitely the best one:
Pass the response type to your call, e.g. `this.http.get<ResponseType>(...)` in order to tell the function that this type will be returned.

You should of course define the response type, e.g.:

```
export interface ResponseType {
  total: number, 
  page: number, 
  page_size: number, 
  cursor?: CursorType, 
  result: ResultType[]
}
```

Note: `CursorType` and `ResultType` are not yet defined, since I do not know your data structure in detail.

Comment: Ok, so I should define the Response Type for the HTTPS requests so that It knows the all properties, and then I can use those properties. If I'm not wrong that is what you mean rite? and I just updated the data Structure please take a look

Comment: Yes, you should always define the types you are handling. Of course for the first test you can just pass `this.get<any>(...)` to tell that any data type will be responded, but this is not a good practice. You should definitely include the correct types.